# meaning of the AND operator in this line

Tags: javascript

What is the meaning of && in this JavaScript code?

```
function doIt(a) {
    var b = a.parents(),
    c = 1;

    return b.each(function() {
        jQuery(this).hasClass("free-content") && (c = 0)
    }), c
}
```

normally I would think this would be a logical operator AND, but I can't figure out what it does in this line.

Comment: Try to get the non-minified source.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The logical **AND** operator in this case is used in place of an **IF**-statement. It will set `c` to `0` if `jQuery(this).hasClass("free-content")` returns a truthy value.

It's equivalent to:

```
if (jQuery(this).hasClass("free-content")) {
    c = 0;
}
```

You wondering what it means is actually the reason I dislike this type of coding and consider it a bad practice. It's hard to read and can create confusion, which in turn can create bugs.

---

It's also worth noting what logical **AND** returns, if you want to use the returned value:

> (Logical AND) Returns expr1 if it can be converted to false; otherwise, returns expr2. Thus, when used with Boolean values, && returns true if both operands are true; otherwise, returns false.

Here's an example showing, in my opinion, bad code since it's hard to follow:

```
var foo = bar && baz || qux;
```

The above code is equivalent to:

```
var foo;
if (bar && baz) {
    foo = baz;
} else {
    foo = qux;
}
```

Summary: Do not use logical operators as a *nifty* way to replace IF-statements or to save keystrokes. It will most likely come back and bite you or someone else in the ass.

I know there will be people arguing against me on this (usually the same people who doesn't want to use semicolon because ASI), but it's just a really bad idea to write code that only an expert would understand. There's no argument against it.

Answer (score 2):

```
return b.each(function () {

    jQuery(this).hasClass("free-content") && (c = 0)
}), c
```

`b.each` loops over all entries in `b`, and checks whether the current element has the class `free-content` set. **Only** if that yields true, the second part of the expression is evaluated – because they are concatenated via `&&`, and JavaScript stops evaluating such an expression when the first part is false, because then the whole expression can’t become true any more.

So if there *is* an element with that class, the second part is evaluated – and thereby `c` is set to the value `0` (because that’s the assignment operator `=` there, and not a comparison).

And after that `each` loop is finished, the value of `c` is returned to the outside – because `each()` and `c` are connected via the [comma operator `,`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) here, which evaluates its operands from left to right and then “returns” the second one.

---

JavaScript allows a lot of “fancy” coding like this, but as Marcus already said in his answer, that is hard to read, and there is no actual advantage here over, say

```
b.each(function() {
    if(jQuery(this).hasClass("free-content")) {
      c = 0;
      return false;
    }
});
return c;
```

I added the `return false` here inside the `each` loop, because once we found an element with that class, we don’t need to search the rest of them any more – that’s something that the person who came up with the original code forgot to do in all their “fancy-ness” … their loop will continue to iterate over all of `b`’s elements, not matter if it finds the element it is looking for in the first round already.